# Could someone take me through the process of plotting the locus of $\frac{1-iwt}{1+iwt}$ as $w$ varies on an Argand plane?

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions, locus

> Find the locus of $$\dfrac{1-iwt}{1+iwt}$$ where $w \in \mathbb{C}, t \in
> > \mathbb{R}$

My method so far was to split it into real and imaginary parts then set $x=\Re(z)$ and $y=\Im(z)$ then solve to get an equation in terms of $x$ and $y$ : $(x^2+y^2=1)$.

The problem is this doesn't tell me the boundaries. The plot should in fact only be below the Real axis - how do I get that boundary?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess, $j=\sqrt{-1}$. What is $w$?

Comment: yeah it is, good ol' engineering notation. I've edited the question and clarified it a bit.

Comment: What is $\;t\;$ ?

Comment: t is a constant

Comment: Well, if that constant isn't positive then the plot definitely won't be all the time below the real axis, @Supertod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's check, assuming you meant $\;t\in\Bbb R\;$ and, of course, also $\;w\in\Bbb R^+\;$ :

$$\frac{1-wti}{1+wti}=\frac{(1-wti)(1-wti)}{|1+wti|^2}=\frac{1-w^2t^2-2wti}{|1+wti|^2}$$

$$=\frac{1-w^2t^2}{|1+wti|^2}-\frac{2wt}{|1+wti|^2}i$$

But then the above is in the lower complex semiplane iff $\;t>0\;$ ...

Comment: Ohh! So it's just the negative in front of the complex term which restricts it to the lower complex plane - that makes sense, thanks. (seems so simple now!)

Comment: Yes but **only if $\;t>0\;$** , @Supertod !!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to plot the Argument on a Bode diagram would you?

Comment: I don't even know what  Bode diagram is, @Supertod

Comment: It's a plot of the Argument against (wt) on a logarithmic scale. My notes give the argument as -2tan^-1(wt) but I can't see how they get that.

Comment: By definition, @Supertod :$$\arg\frac{1-wti}{1+wti}=\arctan\frac{-2wt}{1-w^2t^2}$$which, btw, doesn't seem to be equal to what you wrote...

Comment: Good, I thought I was going crazy. [This is what I had to go off.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dz0at565qhib5zz/Screenshot%202013-12-31%2013.26.34.png) Thanks for your help.